# Accessing localhost from outside

Tags: android, node.js

I have looked for some way to run node.js server on my android device. I found some good article describing it :  https://medium.freecodecamp.com/building-a-node-js-application-on-android-part-1-termux-vim-and-node-js-dfa90c28958f#.xrh3v0du1.   I have followed the tutorial and installed linux vm  on my device and installed node.js. I have successed to run my node.js script and access it from android browser. But I can't find any way to open this page outside my android device by ip address.

Comment: Have you found the ip-address of your android device? What happens when you try to access that with the correct port?

Comment: yes, on whatismyip.com.    nothing, can't find

Comment: How do you connect to the internet. If you are on wifi you probably have an internal ip, given by your router. http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2984/how-can-i-see-what-ip-address-my-android-phone-has

Comment: I have tried 2 ways : by wifi & by 3G. it's same, nothing

Comment: When you use 3G your telco could block the port. By wifi you probably have an internal IP that you will not get from whatsmyip. You need to list it on your device. What port are you running on?

Answer (score 3):

You can access your localhost android running your Node, if your TelCo allow, following the below steps. **Note:** this is only valid when your mobile is connected using your phone data-plan (2-3-4-5... G data), and **not** when it's using a wi-fi connection. To be clear: your app, on your mobile, only serves content, by the below method, if this mobile **is not** using wi-fi data.

1 - setup an account in a dynamic dns provider website (good plans are always paid). There you will configure an URL like http://muhlinin.mydyndns.com which will be pointing to a dynamic IP number;

2 - install the respective dynamic dns app into your mobile, this app will forward your current IP number to your dynamic dns account, something that assures every request to http://muhlinin.mydyndns.com always will find your mobile to respond to that request, whatever IP your mobile has at the request time;

3 - on your android, running (for example) Termux and Node, make your **.js server script** listen to a not default port (cause the default, 80, may be closed by your TelCo), for example, 8000, on the dynamic url you got following itens 1 and 2 showed above. Something like this: http://muhlinin.mydyndns.com:8000

Of course, if your mobile turns off, or the respective dyn dns app is closed or not started, or your Node server is closed or not started, every call to http://muhlinin.mydyndns.com:8000 will result in error. So, in order to have everything working, you have to have the previous 3 steps done correctly **and**
 all opened and started on your mobile server:

1 - dyn dns app;

2 - Node.js runtime;

3 - your serverscript.js (which you will start by doing a simple 'node serverscript.js' on Termux.

Answer (score 1):

Try running `ifconfig` in the terminal and look at the `wlan0` entry for the `inet addr:` field to find your ip on your wifi.

Comment: Ipconfig for wlan0 returns me 192.168.1.11