# How can i connect to my LOCALHOST using other PC,TAB,ETC

Tags: php, apache, xampp, localhost

I wanna ask how can I connect to my `localhost` using other devices ..

I rely to this link
[Localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9682262/how-do-i-connect-to-this-localhost-from-another-computer-on-the-same-network)

But it doesn't work for me ...

Can anyone help me about this ?

Comment: This can be of help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42262832/5885018

Comment: From a different device try the IP address of the device running xampp

Answer (score 0):

You need to run a server on WAMP or XAMP on the server machine

Then you need to make sure your code is running . Then from the other machine browser : //IP Address

This will take you in to your code